# Как изменять PySimpleGUI.Txt() с помощью переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

**Задача**: Сделать текст в окне, который будет изменяться в реальном времени от изменения переменной

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
f=open('conf.txt','r')
conf=f.readline()
f.close()
if conf==0:
    condition='#Files decripted'
else:
    condition='#Files encripted'
...
layout = [
[sg.Txt('',key="condition")]
]
...
event, values = window.read()
window[condition].Update(f"{str(condition)}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вместо

   > window[condition].Update(f"{str(condition)}")

Используй:

> window.Element("condition").Update(condition)

2. У тебя не обновляется значение поля, так как функция window.read() останавливает поток выполнения программы до момента, пока не будет действия в интерфейсе. 
   Одним из способов является использование кнопки: (после нажатия ok текст изменится)

> ```
> layout = [
> [sg.Text(size=(20,1), key="condition")],
> [sg.Ok()]
> ]
>
> window = sg.Window('', layout)
> while True:
>     event, values = window.read()
>     window.Element("condition").Update(condition)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

window.Element("condition").Update(condition) - это старый способ (в документации к PySimpleGUI об этом говориться и рекомендуется использовать window[condition].Update())

А проблема с авто обновлением окна решается путем указания таймаута в мс:

event, values = window.read(100)